# How do I use Django's ORM to return a group of rows only when 3 or more rows will be GROUPed?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Given the following Model:

```
class Enquiry(models.Model):
    enquiryparent = models.ForeignKey('self',default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.SmallIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=40,blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    registered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can write the following query in Django:

Count for a particular type say 'x' where mobile is unique across three days (using registered date) for the complete set...

example:

```
id, type, mobile, registered
1, 2, 988, 01/11/2011
1, 2, 988, 02/11/2011
1, 2, 988, 03/11/2011
1, 4, 988, 04/11/2011
1, 2, 988, 05/11/2011
1, 2, 988, 06/11/2011
1, 2, 988, 07/11/2011
1, 2, 555, 07/11/2011
```

The result should be:

```
id, type, mobile, registered
1, 2, 988, 03/11/2011
1, 2, 988, 05/11/2011
1, 2, 555, 07/11/2011
```

Count total = 3.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "unique"? Your example is not clear enough.

Comment: If number appears more than once in 3 days span, it is counted only once. Right? Too complex for sql.

Comment: @Digivampire, #Skirmantas has explained it correctly - Just repeating, if a number appears more than once in 3 days span, it should be counted as once.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly it seems like this should be doable, but I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with Django's ORM. I think the basic idea would probably look like:

- Select by `id` (`id == 1` in your example), a static integer column that always equals 1, and a dynamic column like `sum(static1)`
- Filter by `type` (like `type == 2` in your example)
- Sort by `registered`
- Group by `mobile`
- Filter where `sum(static1)` is 3 or greater

I know that this is possible in raw SQL, but I don't know how to do it in Django's ORM. Your other option is to simply write a `for` loop that accumulates the results.